# Create Object With Parallel Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, rubygems

I'm trying to introduce some concurrency into my project.

I'm playing with the [parallel gem](https://github.com/grosser/parallel) now, and am having a problem creating an object inside of a parallel process.

```
Parallel.map(["a"], :in_processes => 8) do |i|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
    User.create
  end
end
```

Results in:

```
/Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/parallel-0.8.1/lib/parallel.rb:279:in `dump': no _dump_data is defined for class Binding (TypeError)
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/parallel-0.8.1/lib/parallel.rb:279:in `process_incoming_jobs'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/parallel-0.8.1/lib/parallel.rb:257:in `block in worker'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/parallel-0.8.1/lib/parallel.rb:250:in `fork'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/parallel-0.8.1/lib/parallel.rb:250:in `worker'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/parallel-0.8.1/lib/parallel.rb:238:in `block in create_workers'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/parallel-0.8.1/lib/parallel.rb:237:in `each'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/parallel-0.8.1/lib/parallel.rb:237:in `create_workers'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/parallel-0.8.1/lib/parallel.rb:201:in `work_in_processes'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/parallel-0.8.1/lib/parallel.rb:106:in `map'
    from (irb):15:in `irb_binding'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80:in `eval'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80:in `evaluate'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/context.rb:254:in `evaluate'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:159:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:273:in `signal_status'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:156:in `block in eval_input'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:243:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `loop'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `catch'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `each_top_level_statement'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:70:in `block in start'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `catch'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `start'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
Parallel::DeadWorker: Parallel::DeadWorker
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/parallel-0.8.1/lib/parallel.rb:51:in `rescue in work'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/parallel-0.8.1/lib/parallel.rb:48:in `work'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/parallel-0.8.1/lib/parallel.rb:216:in `block (4 levels) in work_in_processes'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/parallel-0.8.1/lib/parallel.rb:352:in `with_instrumentation'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/parallel-0.8.1/lib/parallel.rb:215:in `block (3 levels) in work_in_processes'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/parallel-0.8.1/lib/parallel.rb:210:in `loop'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/parallel-0.8.1/lib/parallel.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in work_in_processes'
    from /Users/tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@arcsite_mysql/gems/parallel-0.8.1/lib/parallel.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in in_threads'
```

Any variation of the parallel block seems to result in the same error.  Removing the call to `create` allows the program to function as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what you are returning is not dumpable, so either return nil or use Parallel.each alternatively Maybe the with_connection does not actually return the user object but something weird ... You can also try to return user.attributes instead of the full user object

Answer (score 0):

http://ruby.zigzo.com/2012/01/29/the-parallel-gem-and-postgresql-oh-and-rails/

According to the above Mario's post, PostgreSQL does not allow using the same connection for more than one thread. I am wondering if the MySQL is the same, plus MySQL may put lock while accessing it.  Here is the solution for parallel working on PostgreSQL: ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reconnect!